# Failed to find the XML file at location (unable to activate publishing feature)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I first tried to activate the publishing feature via the UI, but it doesn't display.  One of the ways to fix this problem, from what I've read, is the do it via stsadm.

When I try to activate the publishing feature I get the error below.

stsadm -o activatefeature -name PublishingWeb -url https://{servername)

Failed to find the XML file at location '15\Template\Features\PublishingWeb\feature.xml'

What's the work around?  I'm using SharePoint 2013 Foundation.

Comment: Publishing features have always been an enterprise sku feature and not available in foundation

Answer (score 1):

Publishing features have always been an enterprise sku feature and not available in foundation.